# Derivative of squared Heavyside function

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I dont understand why the derivative of the squared Heavyside function is just $\delta(t)$
$$\begin{align*}g(t)&=\theta(t)^2 \\ g'(t) &= (\theta^2(t))'=(\theta(t))'=\delta(t)\end{align*}$$
in distributional sense.

I know that $(\theta(t))'=\delta(t)$ but I dont understand why $(\theta^2(t))'=(\theta(t))'$.

I thought that the derivative would be $$(\theta(t)^2)' = 2 \theta(t) \delta(t) =2 \theta(0) \delta(t) $$

Could you please explain that?

---

The Heavyside function
$$
\theta(t) = \begin{cases}
0\quad \text{ if } t\le 0\\
1\quad \text{ if }t>0.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: It's because by definition (your last equation), we have $\theta(t)^2 = \theta(t)$. This is consistent with your own conclusion provided you interpret $\theta(0) = 1/2$ (which is rather common to do).

Comment: And the value of $\theta(0)$ doesn't really matter.

Comment: @md2perpe, how come that is the case?

Comment: Do you the definition of distributions and how ordinary functions ($L^1_{\text{loc}}$) are seen as distributions?

Comment: @md2perpe, yes I know that ordinary functions are part of the set that is distributions.

Comment: Do you know how ordinary functions are considered being distributions?

Comment: @md2perpe Basically, any locally differentiatable funcation is a distribution. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, I'm asking if you know *how* a locally integrable function becomes a distribution. A function $f$ maps a number $x$ to a number $f(x),$ but a distribution $u$ maps a test function $\phi \in C^\infty_c$ to a number $\langle u, \phi \rangle.$ A distribution, in contrast to a function, doesn't really have a value at an individual point.

Comment: I took the liberty to remove the tag "theta functions", because that phrase strongly tends to refer to things not related at all to the Heaviside function. That is, the fact that quite a few people do denote the Heaviside step function by $\theta$ is disconnected from an assertion that it is "a theta-function".

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you should know about distributions.

0. Distributions are defined as linear functionals on a space of compactly supported and infinitely differentiable functions. When an ordinary function  $f$ is treated as a distribution, it is by the mapping $\phi \mapsto \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\,\phi(x)\,dx.$
1. Distributions do not have point-wise values. For example, what value you set $\theta(0)$ to doesn't matter. The integral above (with $f=\theta$) will not change value when $\theta(0)$ is changed.
2. In general, you cannot multiply distributions. For example, $\theta\delta$ isn't well-defined.

Comment: Yet point-wise valued distributions are regularly used in quantum field theory (where the $\theta(0)=1/2$ convention is essential), while $\theta \delta$ shows up often in stochastic process theory. So there are many practical uses of distributions which run counter to their traditionally-defined characteristics within the theory of distributions.

Comment: @md2perpe Indeed.  $\theta \delta$ has no distributional interpretation.